# Wrong theme for dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

My application have dark theme. I want to show dialog with light theme.

I create own dialog, extend from `android.app.Dialog`. In constructor of dialog I set:

```
super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);
```

As result I see correct background of dialog (white), but inverse text colors/backgrounds for `TextView` and `Button`. Inverse colors - colors for dark theme.

But why?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default dialog theme you can use in your code. I hope this will help you

```
   super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

Comment: in this case I get dark theme of dialog (also as application), but I want to have light theme for dialog. Try `android.R.style.Theme_Light`, anyway see dark theme.

Comment: For dialog you will get dark theme which is default, but if you need light theme then you have to create styles by your own having styles.xml file

Comment: But why I can't use standart android light theme?

Comment: Light theme for activity not for dialog so you have to apply background and text color for your custom dialogs.